# How to add new axioms to classical Peano Arithmetic to obtain a non-standard theory.

Tags: arithmetic, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

What is a simple (the simplest?) axiom which can be added to the usual PA axioms so that the new "non-standard PA theory" no longer has the Standard Model as one of its models? Assuming of course that the new axiom is consistent with the original axioms.

EDIT: I intend a first order theory. If possible by adding a single new axiom. If absolutely necessary, then an RE axiom schema.

Comment: You mean adding a constant $\gamma$ and infinitely many axioms $\gamma\neq 0$, $\gamma\neq 1$, ...

Comment: I see what you are saying, and it would do the job alright. Except it would obviously be more than one axiom. Is it clear that we cannot do better?

Comment: @user10354138 That axiom explicitly contradicts one of the PA axioms. So there is no model for your theory at all, standard or not.'

Comment: That is interesting to me. I started reading a paper in which the theory in question is required to have only non-standard models of PA. It seemed an aside point initially. But I began wondering how to achieve it. On second thought I can believe that it might be just as impossible as to construct a theory which has only the standard model. Because the new attempted axiom meaning "the theory does not have the standard model" has a negation resembling "the theory only has the standard model". Probably my question is simply too naive.

Comment: I am not an expert, but the approach user10354138 gives is the usual one to force the model to be nonstandard.  There is a proof that first order logic cannot force there to only be the standard model.  You would like the induction axiom to say "all numbers are standard" but that is a second order statement.

Comment: It's not very simple, but does $\lnot \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ work?

Comment: @Ross Millikan : I believe you may force the standard model by adding every statement that is true in the standard model as an axiom to make a first order theory. But it is "impossible", because we cannot effectively determine which statements are true, The approach mentioned by user10354138 is a straightforward axiom schema that forces a nonstandard model. This is not a contradiction, because the negation of the conjunction of axioms in the schema is not itself a schema, since it becomes a logical  disjunction.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge : Adding $\neg$Con() as an axiom to PA might kill off some models. But are you certain that it is consistent with PA and that it rules out the standard model in particular?

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen: I believe so, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305133/is-conpa-true-in-standard-model

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen: And $\lnot \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ is consistent with $\mathsf{PA}$, assuming $\mathsf{PA}$ is itself consistent.  If it were not, then $\mathsf{PA}$ would prove $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, which by Godel's second incompleteness theorem it cannot do.

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen: I don't believe that is sufficient.  There could be more elements than the standard ones.  There are constraints on what is true about them-they are all greater than all the naturals so every statement that is true for all $n$ large enough is true of all of them.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Indeed, doesn't upward Lowenheim-Skolem guarantee that there are other models (of arbitrarily high cardinality) which satisfy exactly the same first-order statements as the standard one?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes.  I believe one can also get countable models that satisfy all the same first order statements as standard "true arithmetic".

Comment: @NateEldredge I was talking about a comment that seems to have disappeared, where it was asserted that PA plus the one axiom "there exists a non-zero non-asuccessor" added had the required property.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Ah, I see.  I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new axiom must be consistent but not hold in the standard model, it must be undecidable in $\sf PA$. But for most (all?) of the statements which we have proved undecidable in $\sf PA$, we know whether or not they hold in the standard model. We can therefore obtain a nonstandard theory by adding the statement or its negation to $\sf PA$.

So answering the question simply requires us to find the simplest statement which is known to be undecidable in $\sf PA$. Of course Gödel sentence was the first known example of such, but since then various simpler undecidable sentences have been found. The most famous are [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) (proved undecidable by Kirby and Paris), and the [Strengthened Finite Ramsey Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) (proved undecidable by Paris and Harrington). Both these statements are known to be true in the standard model, so we obtain a non-standard theory by adding the negation of one of them as an axiom.